# Can't access Pending user's profile info

Tags: users, registration, status

I have public user registration enabled with the "Verify email addresses" setting checked.

User registration form includes these "action" and "redirect" hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="signup/payment/{id}">
```

User's ID is coming through correctly in the last segment of the URL, but I can't fetch their profile. This is throwing a template error:

```
{% set userId = craft.request.lastSegment() %}
{% set profile = craft.users.id(userId) | first %}
```

But if I hardcode an existing Active user's ID it works:

```
{% set profile = craft.users.id(30) | first %}
```

Is there a way to access a Pending member's (albeit limited) profile info? What I really need to do is insert their email address into a subsequent form on the success page.

Comment: What template error is being throw? What does this output? `{{ craft().request.lastSegment() }} `

Comment: Very late update, but this works...

`{% set user = craft.users.id(craft.request.lastSegment).status('pending').first() %}`

Comment: Would you mind adding that as an official answer, Roger?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
{% set user = craft.users.id(craft.request.lastSegment).status('pending').first() %}
```